# Difference between &T and T/&, ~T and T/~

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

What is the difference between having the pointer type prefixing the type versus having it postfix with a slash prior to it. What does the slash even mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax T/~ and T/& is basically deprecated (I'm not even sure if the compiler still accepts it).  In the initial phases of the transition to the new vector scheme, [T]/~ indicated a unique pointer to a vector and [T]/& indicated a slice.  These types are now written ~[T] and &[T] respectively.  The slash is still used for fixed-length vectors, e.g., [int]/3.  This is exactly equivalent to the C type int[3].